# SetTag() and GetTag() in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, xamarin, expandablelistview

I have a problem in my GetChildView in my expandableAdapter.In fact i would have a expandable listview with multiple selection for that i used ViewHolder but i had some problem with view.SetTag(holder)and holder=(ViewHolder)GetTag().this is my code for GetChildView.Please does anyone have an idea or a solution for expandablelistView with multiple selection?

```
public override View GetChildView (int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool    isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
ViewHolder holder = null;
View row = convertView;
string name=GetChild(groupPosition, childPosition).ToString();
    if(row==null)
    {
row = Context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.List_selection_childrenItem, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.code = (TextView)row.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBox1);
        holder.name = (CheckBox)row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.item);

       row.SetTag(holder);
       holder.name.CheckedChange += checkedd_CheckedChange;
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder)row.GetTag();
    }

        var child = GetChild1(groupPosition, childPosition);

holder.code.SetText(name, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
holder.name.Checked = GetChild1(groupPosition, childPosition).IsChecked;
checkedd.CheckedChange+=checkedd_CheckedChange;
holder.name.SetTag(child);
    return row;
}
```

Comment: What's your problem? .. and i'll appreciate if you can post more code

Comment: my problem is that i can't convert Viewholder in Java.Lang.Object in this line   `holder = (ViewHolder)row.GetTag();` also GetTag an SetTag need a key but i didn't know what's that key